# Word for an idea that is often touted as true but in fact the opposite is true?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes an idea that is often held out as true or used as a rationale though in fact the opposite is true. Something like "common misconception" or "antipattern" come close, but I feel as though there's a better word I'm missing.

Examples:

"Refusing to use popular security algorithms because everyone knows how they work is a [word], since it is *because* everyone knows how they work that they are so safe."

Not necessarily saying I 100% agree with the following, but someone who advocates for Keto might say this:

"Trying to lose weight by cutting out fat is a [word], because replacing carbohydrates and proteins with fat allows the body to enter ketosis, which is one of the best states for losing weight."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A "[common] mistake", perhaps?

Comment: @Keepthesemind Interesting, that does seem to fit well into those examples. I think I'm looking more for something that describes an idea than an action. *Fallacy* comes to mind as another word that might work.

Comment: _Myth_? _OED_ definition: A widespread but untrue or erroneous story or belief; a widely held misconception; a misrepresentation of the truth.

Answer (score 2):

It is a "**myth**" or it is "**mythical**".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/myth

Answer (score 1):

The second meaning of ['Canard' as per Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canard) may be a good fit.

> Canard
>
> 1a : a false or unfounded report or story.
>   *especially* : a fabricated report
>
> '*The report about a conspiracy proved to be a canard*'.
>
> b : a groundless rumor or belief
>
> '*the widespread canard that every lawyer is dishonest*'

Though you might want to rejig your examples slightly for the best flow:

> "The idea of refusing to use popular security algorithms because everyone knows how they work is a canard, since it is precisely because everyone knows how they work that they are so safe."